# Why is my telegram bot not able to answer?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, telegram-bot

I would like to use my Raspberry Pi as a weather station. Therefore I bought a "Debo Sen Rain" and a "Debo Sens BME680". Because I've never worked with Python before, I copied two scripts out of the Internet. They do both work very well. Yesterday I created a telegram bot, which should send me the current measured data, when sending "/data" or "/rain". So I copied the original scripts in a new python script and embedded the bot. Unfortunately, It doesn't work but I can't locate the error.

Here's my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
#coding: utf8

# telegram import
import time, datetime
import telepot
from telepot.loop import MessageLoop
# import os

# bme680 import
import board
from busio import I2C
import adafruit_bme680

i2c = I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
bme680 = adafruit_bme680.Adafruit_BME680_I2C(i2c, debug = False)
bme680.sea_level_pressure = 971.91
temperature_offset = 0

temperatur = "Temperatur: %0.1f C" % (bme680.temperature + temperature_offset)
gas = "Gas: %d ohm" % bme680.gas
luftfeuchtigkeit = "Luftfeuchtigkeit: %0.1f %%" % bme680.relative_humidity
luftdruck = "Luftdruck: %0.3f hPa" % bme680.pressure

messdaten = temperatur + "\n" + gas + "\n" + luftfeuchtigkeit + "\n" +  luftdruck

#rain import
from time import sleep
from gpiozero import InputDevice

rain = InputDevice(18)

while True:
    if rain.is_active:
        regen = "Es regnet. Fenster zu!"
    else:
        regen = "Es regnet nicht"


now = datetime.datetime.now()

def action(msg):
    chat_id=msg['chat']['id']
    command = msg['text']
    
    print ('Received: %s' % command)
    
    if command == '/hi':
        telegram_bot.sendMessage (chat_id, str("Kuckuck"))
    
    elif command == '/data':
        telegram_bot.sendMessage (chat_id, str(messdaten))
        
    elif command == '/rain':
        telegram_bot.sendMessage (chat_id, str(regen))

telegram_bot = telepot.Bot('XXX:XXXXXXX')
print (telegram_bot.getMe())

MessageLoop(telegram_bot, action).run_as_thread()
print ('Up and Running...')

# Keep the program running.
while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
```

(I tried to run the script with the Python editor "Mu".)

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets take a closer look at this part of your code:

```py
while True:
    if rain.is_active:
        regen = "Es regnet. Fenster zu!"
    else:
        regen = "Es regnet nicht"
```

Sinde the `while True` will **never** quit, the Telegram code below will never be reached.

You'd need to rework you loopings, update the `regen` variable in the same loop as you'd send your Telegram messages